# Book about adventure on Jupiter

Tags: story-identification, novel, novella

I read several of my, now ex-, brother-in-law's scifi books back in the early nineties without really paying too much attention to the titles or authors; just wanted something to read.  One keeps coming back up in memories every now and then and I would like to read it again. It wasn't a short story but it may have only been novella in length.

The story was about a human from Earth who went to Jupiter (maybe Venus?) and communicated his adventures there back to the book's author on Earth via telepathy (mentioned in the opening chapters).  On his initial decent down to Jupiter, he encounters, just below the cloud canopy, incredibly tall trees in which people live.  If I recall correctly, there were some rather large spiders up there, too.  He eventually makes it down to the ground and travels all over the planet on his adventure.  I'm having difficulty recalling any further scenes from the book other than bits and pieces that are hard to describe, let alone put in context.  And that's even if they're from the same book.

Comment: Initial thought this might be the Callisto series by Lyn Carter. (Human transported to Moon of Jupiter) the first book is Jandar of Callisto. I know Large Insects are in the story, but don't remember enough to know if there are Large trees or if the insects are spider like. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jandar_of_Callisto  The books are the same or similar to the John Carter of Mars (Barsoom) boks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like one of the books in Edgar Rice Burroughs' "Carson of Venus" series - possibly the first one, [*Pirates of Venus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirates_of_Venus).

- Carson Napier relates his (supposedly true, of course) story to Edgar Rice Burroughs via telepathic communications, since he's on Venus.
- He was actually trying to travel to Mars, but wound up crash-landing on Venus. His parachute gets caught in a tree; he finds that the trees on Venus are humongous.
- He encounters a race of humans on Venus, as well as a giant spider. He believes his companion (a man named Kamlot) has been killed by the Spider's venom, but eventually discovers he's just paralyzed.

The "Carson of Venus" series covers 4 complete novels:

- [Pirates of Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirates_of_Venus)
- [Lost on Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_on_Venus)
- [Carson of Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carson_of_Venus)
- [Escape on Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_on_Venus)

Plus, a novella, "The Wizard of Venus", Burroughs' last Venus story, published with other material in a book [named for the novella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Venus)

Answer (score 6):

Obviously not set in Jupiter, but you said "maybe Venus" so

#### Pirates of Venus

By Edgar Rice Burroughs (who also wrote about Tarzan and John Carter of Mars).  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirates_of_Venus):

> A few days later Carson shows up at Tarzana, telling the story of his life including how he grew up in India, learning telepathy from the Hindu mystic Chand Kabi, how he lived with his mother's grandfather John Carson, and how he lost his mother. Revealing an intent to fly a rocket to Mars, he fades from view only to enter through the door again. He has used telepathy for the meeting to ascertain they can uphold telepathic communication so that the author may become the medium through which he tells the story of his adventures.

So telepathic narration.

> Falling through two thick layers of clouds he is unaware of his surroundings (except for a faint luminosity from below) until the parachute gets stuck in the branches of a tree. Freeing himself from the parachute he starts descending and soon learns the trees are of enormous proportions.

So giant trees below a cloud canopy.  I won't quote from the summary, but the next chapter reveals that men live there.

> Tarel turns out to be the web of a spider. Carson saves Kamlot from a giant spider (targo), but Kamlot dies.

So giant spiders.

Carson Napier then proceeds to travel the world and have many adventures.

There is an entire series of books.  This is the first one.  You could have read it in a magazine in serial form.  Or as a relatively short (by modern standards) book.